# Redirect URL but not subdirectories IIS 8

Tags: redirect, iis-8

Currently, I have IIS 8 set up to answer www.IPO.is with a static website. I then have asp.net projects answering to specific sub-directories of www.IPO.is (e.g. www.IPO.is/test).

[image: My current IIS setup.]

Now I'm moving the static website to a different location and URL so I want the old URL to redirect to the new project. (ipo.keldan.is)

Is there any way to have IIS answer www.ipo.is with a redirect but still serve www.ipo.is/test as before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good hint from Mohsin Mehmood I managed to find a solution for this problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="IPO Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.+)" negate="true" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://ipo.keldan.is" redirectType="Permanent" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)ipo.is" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This matches any URL that does not have any sub-directories for the host ipo.is (with any variants of http/https and www/non-www.

Comment: Instead of 302(Found) redirect I think 301 (permanent) redirect will be more suitable from SEO perspective

Comment: Yes, correct. I've changed it locally (I used 302 while testing to avoid the cache).

Answer (score 1):

You can use IIS UrlRewrite extension. Create a web.config file at the root of your static website directory and then paste in the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect rule" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="/$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://ipo.keldan.is" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^ipo.is$" />
                    </conditions>

                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Ensure you have UrlRewrite extension installed before applying this update. You can install UrlRewrite using Microsoft WebPlatform installer

Comment: This only seems to match the URL after the first /. http://ipo.is/ipo.is gets redirected to ipo.is/ipo.keldan.is but ipo.is does not get redirected anywhere.

Comment: After a lot of trial and error, I figured it out. You're very near the mark. Thanks a lot for the help. <3 (see my answer)